# Find parallelogram within the grid

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

If there is a 10*10 grid randomly filled by 1s and 0s, and to find the parallelogram with the biggest size(with the most number of 1s), what is the best algorithm for this task?

Example of the grid

[image: example of the grid]

Valid parallelograms are in either red and blue for example:

[image]

appreciate if someone could help!
thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your reply!                                                                                       http://pastebin.com/jFJFyj6W here is what I have gone so far , with rectangular, but not with the parallelogram shift to the right or left. but looping through all the points for all the possibilities creates lot of nested for loops and I am not sure if i am on the right direction.                                            the function def grid_slice(): is the one that find rectangular ones                          thank you so much!

Comment: I don't think looping for loops is the right way to go, because then your approach doesn't scale well. I agree that considering the rectangular case first and then shifting the parallelograms is a good way to go though. This seems like a dynamic programming problem (store the results of a computation in an array, and use those again), but I can't see a solution, and I've never been much good at dynamic programming :/

Comment: thanks you very much for your answer! This is an interesting question and the solution is not very straight forward, I will try to find out a better solution and if I do , I will post back to you :)